# How can i change the color of a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, colors

I've created a simple code that looks a bit like "Impossible Game". I'm new with javascript so my question might sound a bit strange but i've created a few opjects like you can see below. When i change the color with ctx.fillstyle all my objects change this specific color. How can i give each object a different color?

Thanks ;)

```
var PlayerX;
var Blocka;
var Ground

var canvas = document.getElementById("gamefield");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var Gamespeed = 5;
var Gravity = 0.9;
var Score = 0;
var velocity = 0.01;
var jumping;

PlayerX = new Player();
Blocka = new Block(1);
Ground = new Gameground();

setInterval(Update, 20);

function startGame() {

}

function Player() {
  // this staat voor verwijzing naar zichzelf
  this.width = 30;
  this.height = 50;
  this.x = canvas.width / 4;
  this.y = canvas.height / 3 * 2;
  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }

}

function Block(kolb) {
  this.width = 20;
  this.height = 40;
  this.show = true;
  //this.x = canvas.width/2;
  this.x = canvas.width + 20;
  this.y = (canvas.height / 3 * 2) + 10;
  this.draw = function() {
    this.move();
    if (this.show) {
      if (kolb == 1) {
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
      }
    }
  }
  this.move = function() {
    this.x -= Gamespeed;
    this.death();
  }
  this.death = function() {
    if (this.x <= 20) {
      this.show = false;
    }
  }
}

function Gameground() {
  // this staat voor verwijzing naar zichzelf
  this.width = 800;
  this.height = 150;
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 450;
  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00FFBF"
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
}

function Update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  Blocka.draw();
  PlayerX.draw();
  if (PlayerX.x < Blocka.x + Blocka.width &&
    PlayerX.x + PlayerX.width > Blocka.x &&
    PlayerX.y < Blocka.y + Blocka.height &&
    PlayerX.height + PlayerX.y > Blocka.y) {
    // collision detected!
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  }

  Ground.draw();
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);

function checkKeyPressed(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == "32") { //kijkt of de spatiebalk is ingedrukt

    var interval1, interval2, velo, tijd;

    velo = 0.00001;

    tijd = 20;
    interval1 = setInterval(plus, tijd);

    function plus() {

      if (velo < 20) {
        velo += 1.5;
      } else {
        velo -= 1.5;
      }

      if (PlayerX.y > 480) {
        clearInterval(interval1);
        interval2 = setInterval(min, tijd);
      }

      PlayerX.y += velo;
      console.log(PlayerX.y);
    }

    function min() {

      if (velo < 20) {
        velo += 1.5;
      } else {
        velo -= 1.5;
      }

      if (PlayerX.y < 430) {
        clearInterval(interval2);
      }

      PlayerX.y -= velo;
      console.log(PlayerX.y);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you create [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example?

Comment: You'd need to update `ctx.fillStyle` before you call each `draw()` function.

Comment: Thanks, i've fixed it!

Comment: @Nielsvangils - please post what you did to fix it as an answer and accept it. That way, future users who stumble across this question can share in your knowledge.

Comment: @Frits I just added a ctx.fillstyle in every object like you can see below:  this.draw = function(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00FFBF"
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
 }

Comment: @Nielsvangils Well done! Add that as an answer, not as a comment :)

Comment: @Nielsvangils Doesn't matter. When people google a similar problem and land on this page, they will quickly scroll down to see the accepted (ticked) answer. It's a good practice that also earns you plenty of reputation if the answer is good.

Comment: In case anyone is interested:     https://jsfiddle.net/Nielsvangils/v9hL9d3k/

Comment: @JohnWhite & Nielsvangils, I have added the fix to my code as an edit so that it will be available for future users.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ctx.save();` and `ctx.restore();` before and after your individual color changes.

This will save the current context state before changing the color, and then restore it back to it's original state after that one specific rectangle was drawn, yet before the others are drawn.

See below for example.

```
ctx.save();
ctx.fillStyle = "#00FFBF";
ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
ctx.restore();
```

*--- EDIT ---*

As per the comments on OP's question - another resolution is to ensure that you call the `fillStyle` function before each `fillRect` function. See example and fiddle (provided by OP) below.

```
this.draw = function(){ 
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00FFBF"; 
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height); 
}
```

Here's OP's fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Nielsvangils/v9hL9d3k/